# Printing photos off of Android phone with "Verifiable dates"?

Tags: images

How does one print photos from an Android phone with a date on it?

When the original photo doesn't show a date on the actual image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by verifiable days, but dates are typically recorded as part of the filesystem when the photo is created. A date may also be embedded in the meta data if the image (EXIF data) and this is more reliable when recorded. Of-course, if the date is not correct in the camera when the photo is taken this info will be inaccurate. BTW, EXIF data can record a range of things, including location, camera settings etc. Actually printing the photo depends on the specific software being used.

Comment: You need to find an app which can take exif data out of images and edit the images automatically with the exif data to achieve what you want.